# Reading japanese characters from the body of an IMAP E-Mail

Tags: php, unicode, localization, imap

i try to fetch the body  of the email in japanese  with this code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8');  
$mbox = imap_open ("{localhost:995/pop3/ssl/novalidate-cert}",        "***@*****.com", "*******");
$email="something@something.com";
$num_mensaje = imap_search($mbox,"FROM $email");
$body =  imap_fetchbody($mbox,$num_mensaje[0],"1");

echo imap_8bit($body));
```

but doesn't work for me i see this `*$B$3$s$K$A$O!"$=$N$h$&$J`

any ideas

Thanks in advance

Comment: Define "in japanese" - which encoding does the E-Mail have? UTF-8?

Comment: i dont know the encoding but the email is in japanese characters

Comment: i'm testing with an email wrote in japanese language

Comment: Interesting - I don't know how to deal with character set issues when reading E-Mail through IMAP. There doesn't seem to be much on the topic on Stack Overflow, either. Interested to see what comes up.

Comment: The message headers should describe the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Since `<ESC>$B` is one of the primary control sequences in the JIS encodings, and your output begins `*$B`, it would appear that your data has come from that source.  Try using [mb_convert_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php) from JIS (or SJIS).

Edit: If you are potentially accepting Japanese from multiple encodings, you could look at the [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) function; making use of an appropriate encoding list.

Comment: Yeah, but how can he detect the encoding on a per-message basis? Some japanese messages will be in UTF-8, for example.

Comment: @Pekka - my reading of the question was that he was having specific issues with Japanese encoded text from a single source, but the point is well taken.  I've updated the answer with a note on encoding detection.

Comment: i try  mb_convert_encoding($str, "SJIS"); but it doesn't work and mb_detect_encoding($body); and i obtain ASCII

Comment: i try echo mb_detect_encoding($body, "auto") and i obtain UTF-8

Comment: i try mb_convert_encoding($body,"UTF-8","JIS")   and it works.  Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I've only tried to use this code snippet to decode **ISO-2022-JP messages to UTF-8** and it worked for me.

```
$temp = iconv_mime_decode($email['overview'][0]->subject,0,"ISO-2022-JP");
echo mb_convert_encoding($temp, "UTF-8", "JIS");
```